# Can I change the URL of my AppHarbor application?

Tags: appharbor

When I setup my application at AppHarbor, I chose a URL. However, I'd like to change it. Can that be done?

This is for the _ _ _ _ _.apphb.com URL (not a custom hostname).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not currently possible to change the `*.apphb.com` URL when the application has been created.

The simple solution right now is to create a new application with the name you want and AppHarbor will give you an URL that is as close as possible to the application name.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to make a new application, install all the same add-ons, copy over my database, configure github, and presto!  The site is up and running! Gotta love AppHarbor!